# Facebook Javascript SDK - getLoginStatus callback never called

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having all sorts of fun issues with the Facebook API (which is so simple, this has driven me nuts).  I'm trying to login to Facebook using their requireJS approach.

When attempting to get the login status while first opening the app, the callback is never fired indicating if a user is logged in or not.

I have to keep clearing cookies to even get the login page to popup - and once I do login to Facebook, the login popup says redirecting at the top and is just white.

```js
define([
 'jquery',
 'underscore',
 'backbone',
    'facebook',
    '../models/session',
    'template!../../../html/appView',
    './searchView'
], function( $, _, Backbone, Facebook, SessionModel, AppViewTemplate, SearchView ) {
 'use strict';

 return Backbone.View.extend({
  id: 'app-view',

  searchViews: {},

  views: {},

  events: {
            'click #btn-fb-login' : 'loginWithFacebook'
        },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo( this.model, 'change', this.render, this );

            this.searchView = new SearchView();

            FB.init({
                appId      : 'My App ID',
                status     : true,
                version    : 'v2.3'
            });

            this.checkLoginState( true );
  },

  render: function() {
            console.log( 'rendering' );

            AppViewTemplate.renderToView( this );
            this.$( '#header' ).append( this.searchView.render().$el );
   return this;
  },

        loginWithFacebook: function() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                console.log( response );

                if ( response.authResponse ) {
                    console.log('Fetching authResponse information.... ');

                } else {

                }
            }.bind( this ), {
                scope: 'email'
            });
        },

        checkLoginState: function( checkOnly ) {
            console.log( FB );

            FB.getLoginStatus( function( response ) {
                console.log('response:', response);

                clearInterval( timer );
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                    console.log( 'LOGGED IN!' );
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                } else {
                    if ( !checkOnly ) {
                        this.loginWithFacebook();
                    }
                }
            }.bind( this ) );
        }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my main view I was rendering to body - which was removing fb-root (after facebook had already checked if it existed, so it never created it itself).